# Sending reminder email only to those who have not approved

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, approval-process, sharepoint-email, reminder

Need your support. I have created a workflow where I have 2 approvers to approve a document.
I need to enhance the workflow by sending out email reminders to those who have not approved.

The issue I am facing is when I am using a delay action so once the time is reached it is sending notification to both the approvers even if 1 has approved. Can someone help on the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean variable they will turn to true once wait for approval has passed and after the delay has passed you will check if the boolean variable is false then you send an email.

Here is an example
[image: Work flow example for one person]

Comment: The image example is done for 1 approver but can be easily expanded to contain any amount of approvers